# oauth2 how to verify authorization code is not be attacked

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

To prevent a CSRF attack, we use the 'state' parameter to ensure that the redirect back URL request is not modified (by checking that the 'state' in the request and callback are the same).

However, if a hacker already has an authcode (which is still active, generated by the attacker within 5 minutes and not yet used to exchange token), and replaces this authcode with a normal user's redirect back URL but does not change the 'state', who will check that the 'state' and 'code' are paired?

The client can only verify that the 'state' has not been changed, and only the authorization server can check if the 'authcode' belongs to a unique 'state'. However, OAuth 2.0 does not explicitly require the client to pass both 'state' and 'code' to the server to exchange a token.

Answer (score 1):

This is what [PKCE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) is for, to prove that the party which started authentication is finishing it. Originally it was designed for public clients but is now also recommended for [confidential clients](https://oauth.net/2.1/).

The authorization request looks like this:

```
GET http://login.example.com/oauth/authorize
    ?client_id=myclient
    &redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/callback
    &response_type=code
    &scope=openid profile
    &code_challenge=WhmRaP18B9z2zkYcIlb4uVcZzjLqcZsaBQJf5akUxsA
    &code_challenge_method=S256
    &state=CfDJ8Nxa-YhPzjpBilDQz2C...
```

In your example, when the `code` is substituted, these values are sent in the request for tokens:

```
POST http://login.example.com/oauth/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=mylient
&client_secret=U2U9EnSKx31fUnvgGR3coOUszko5MiuCSI2Z_4ogjIiO5-UbBzIBWU6JQQaljEis
&code=I9xL9DY9jAYHPuHSiW2OpWUaNRW4otei
&grant_type=authorization_code
&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/callback
&code_verifier=HlfffYlGy7SIX3pYHOMJfhnO5AhUW1eOIKfjR42ue28
```

The authorization server will reject the second request, since in request 1 it stored the code issued against the `code_challenge`. Yet the second request has a `code_verifier` that does not match the code sent.